# Neo4j - Cypher statement to build relationships took near half of day to complete with error "Self-suppression not permitted"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Usually I am building relationships between nodes while loading from CSV files. Here is a statement written cypher I used this time to build relationships between nodes. The Language nodes are 39K and the Description nodes are 2M.

```
MATCH (d:Description),(l:Language)
> WHERE d.description_language = l.language_name
> CREATE (d)-[r:HAS_LANGUAGE]->(l);
```

After a long, run the error I got is:

```
Self-suppression not permitted
```

I have created indexes on for the properties to be used in the relationship.

```
Indexes
... 
  ON :Description(woka_id)              ONLINE                             
  ON :Description(description_language) ONLINE                             
  ON :Language(language_id)             ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
  ON :Language(language_name)           ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
...
```

What I am doing wrong here causing such a long time to complete the relationships creation (more than 10 hours)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating relationships from every Description node and there are 2M of them I would just grab the description that are not yet matched and do them in smaller batches.

Something like...

```
match (d:Description)
where not ( d-[:HAS_LANGUAGE]->() )
with d
limit 200000
match (l:Language {language_name: d.description_language} )
create d-[:HAS_LANGUAGE]->l
```

Comment: Why not use `PERIODIC COMMIT`? You should at least mention it since your way seems kinda funky to me.

Comment: I would have but the OP says he is doing the relationship build after `LOAD CSV` in this instance. To my knowledge `PERIODIC COMMIT` is still just a LOAD CSV capability and not in the general cypher feature set.

Comment: I will try both answers.

Comment: I used this answer and I repeated the statement execution until no new relationships were created. Very time effective. All done in less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with a very large cartesian product at the filter step:

```
WHERE d.description_language = l.language_name
```

You could try to `MATCH` the `Descriptions`, group them by their `description_language` and `CREATE` the relationships from there:

```
MATCH (d:Description)
WITH d.description_language AS dl, collect(d) as all_d_for_lang
MATCH (l:Language {language_name: dl})
UNWIND all_d_for_lang AS d
CREATE (l)-[:HAS_LANGUAGE]->(d)
```

If you look at the `PROFILE` of this query you'll see there are less DB hits (limit the number of descriptions in the first `MATCH` for testing).

In general, I think the best way would be to use your CSV files to generate relationships when you create the nodes, i.e. do this application side, not on the database.

Comment: nice answer - I like the collecting descriptions together per languages; I should have thought of that.  Agree that doing it at load time i the best scenario.

Comment: The first solution failed with this error: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space I think DISTINCT may not help since most of the descriptions are distinct. Can't see two books having exactly the same description.

Comment: Yes, the DISTINCT is not necessary since every Description node is matched only once. How much heap did you allocate for neo4j? Try to increase it, the query matches 2M Description nodes, so I'd expect it to eat a lot of memory.

Comment: And for testing you could add `WITH d LIMIT 100` after the first `MATCH`

Comment: don't know how to check the heap, please advise.

Comment: You configure the Java heap space for neo4j in `conf/server-wrapper.conf` (wrapper.java.maxmemory): http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-jvm.html#_configuring_heap_size_and_gc

Comment: Here it is:

wrapper.java.initmemory=4096
wrapper.java.maxmemory=8192

And in the server properties file I have these:

neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=512M

Comment: well, try to increase it ... Maybe you have to solve your problem differently, i.e. by adding relationships from the CSV files.